# Error running selected code generator The database provider attempted to register an implementation of 'IRelationTypeMappingSource'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Before reinstalling visual studio my ASP.NET Core MVC project and scaffolder was working fine.

But after that I'm not able to add new scaffolded item.

[image]

[image]

**By updating all NuGet packages and then run scaffolder it automatically degrades the packages**

**EDIT 1 :**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20200625063143_user_table_added_for_access_control.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20200625063143_user_table_added_for_access_control.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20200625070609_test.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20200625070609_test.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20200701100225_datatype_changed_to_long_of_assetno_in_both_table.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20200701100225_datatype_changed_to_long_of_assetno_in_both_table.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20200730114532_hasShiftingRequest_field_added_in_pc.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20200730114532_hasShiftingRequest_field_added_in_pc.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20200731033230_hasShiftingRequest_field_added_in_pc.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20200731033230_hasShiftingRequest_field_added_in_pc.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20200917095552_trial.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20200917095552_trial.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20201208042418_test.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20201208042418_test.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20201208054030_User_table_mapped_with_laptop_and_desktop.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20201208054030_User_table_mapped_with_laptop_and_desktop.Designer.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Views\AssetDataLaptops\Delete.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Views\AssetDataPcs\Delete.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Views\AssetShiftings\Delete.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Views\AssetShiftings\Details.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Views\AssetShiftings\Edit.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="bootstrap" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.11" />    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.11">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" Version="15.0.4795.1000" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.DirectoryServices" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>



</Project>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Getting build error after degrading EntityFrameworkCore 5 to 3.x

[image]

Comment: Hi @parthraj panchal,can you share your `Project file`?

Comment: Hi @Yinqiu you mean appSetting or sln file ?

Comment: Your `.csproj` file

Comment: @Yinqiu added my cproj file

Comment: Your project version is 3.1,you should not use package `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.2" />`, change it to 3.x

Comment: @Yinqiu getting build error:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'EntityTypeBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Navigation' and no accessible extension method 'Navigation' accepting a first argument of type 'EntityTypeBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) AssetManagement C:\Users\20303286\Documents\repos\AssetManagement\AssetManagement\Migrations\AssetManagementContextModelSnapshot.cs 277 Active

Comment: You can see the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#required-11-dependents).

Comment: @Yinqiu unable to understand that so i just commented those 3  lines and it worked !

Comment: @Yinqiu Yes i can scaffold now, thank  to you. I'll mark your answer for sure.

Comment: Thank :),glad can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your project version is 3.1,you should not use package `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.2" />`.

You need change it to 3.x.

Comment: Hi ,again similar kind of issue im facing during scaffolding.
Now it says "There was a problem running the selected code generator : 'Package restore Failed'" . Rolling back package changes for "AssetManagement".
This time i have added some model (tables) and tried to scaffold MVC controller and Views.